# Change the position of an Icon

Tags: python, interface, add-on

I am creating an addon, but I needed a small help. This is the code

```
    row2.label("Text",icon = 'BLENDER')
```

Now, if I execute it, the Icon is placed before the Text.

Is there anyway to place the Icon after the text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add two labels, one with the text only, and another with the icon only:

```
    row = layout.row()
    row.alignment = 'LEFT'
    row.label("Text")
    row.label(icon='BLENDER')
```

Comment: will not work for menus operator button tho